# Eclipse doesn't search java files generated by JavaCC

Tags: eclipse, javacc

I'm using the JavaCC Eclipse Plug-in 1.5.30 with Eclipse Luna Service 2(4.4.2).
When I use JavaCC to generate java files from the st4tic.jtb program grammar, Eclipse seems to completely ignore them when I do a file search.

In the navigator view, all of the generated files have  appended to their names e.g. NodeList.java <st4tic.jtb>

Answer (score 1):

There is an option for the plugin to not mark generated files as generated.